# NodeJS/Express - Find website IP that made the request

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any way to get the IP of the website that made the request to the API?

I am working on an application that allows multiple websites to access the API, while the end user IP doesn't really matter. Using the Origin header is not really helpful since you can mock it in Postman.

Can I safely allow just a few websites to access the API? Using CORS, from what I know it uses the Origin header as well.
Are other workarounds for this?

Comment: Another way is to provide api key, maybe should you think about it ...

Comment: If the browser is making the request, the server that served the assets has no involvement in the API call.

Comment: @Joe, isn't there any workaround for this? I guess, sending an API key, or a token can easily be copied by anyone to call the API

Comment: Is the goal traceability or authorization?

Comment: In my opinion it is both, since let's say a user can register to "example.com" with email "test@test.com", and he registers as well to "anotherex.com" with the same email, when I authenticate him, I think I should know where he comes from, right?